# Flutter Firebase document.id update problem

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database

I've problem about send 'document.id' value to another page.

My first page is this:

[image: My first page]

I want to update task's header and content. When user's tap to pencil, I navigate to this screen: [image: My second picture]

But, in the update screen there is a problem about 'document.id' as you see. To update the already exist document, I need the document id in the UpdateScreen page but I cant access. What can I do to solve?

My codes:

```dart
 return ListView(
            children: snapshot.data!.docs.map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
              Map<String, dynamic> data =
                  document.data()! as Map<String, dynamic>;
              return Card(
                child: ListTile(
                  title: Text(data['GorevBaslik']),
                  subtitle: Text(data['GorevIcerik']),
                  trailing: Wrap(
                    spacing: 12, // space between two icons
                    children: <Widget>[
                      IconButton(
                          icon: Icon(Icons.edit),
                          onPressed: () async {
                            await Navigator.push(
                                context,
                                MaterialPageRoute(
                                    builder: (context) => UpdateStatusPage()));
                          }),
                      IconButton(
                        icon: Icon(Icons.remove),
                        onPressed: () async {
                          print(document.id);
                         // authService.removeStatus(document.id); //auth olarak değil status olarak değiştir service adını
                          },
                      ), // icon-2
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              );
            }).toList(),
          );
```

and the update pages:

```dart
return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      appBar: AppBar(
        iconTheme: IconThemeData(
          color: Colors.white, //change your color here
        ),
        title: Text(
          "Görev Oluştur",
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
        ),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 120.0, left: 25.0, right: 25.0),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            TextFormField(
              controller: gorevBaslikController,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                  prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.edit), labelText: "Güncellemek istediğiniz görev başlığı"),
            ),
            TextFormField(
              controller: gorevIcerikController,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                  prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.article_rounded),
                  labelText: "Yeni görev içeriği"),
              maxLines: 3,
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 15),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: (){
                //getStatus.addTask(gorevBaslikController.text, gorevIcerikController.text);
                firestore.collection('Task').doc('${auth.currentUser?.email}').collection('tasks').doc(document.id).update(
                  {
                    'GorevBaslik': gorevBaslikController,
                    'GorevIcerik': gorevIcerikController,
                  }
                );
              },
              child: Text(
                "Güncelle",
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the `documentId or document` in the editing file to update the correct document.

```
UpdateScreen(@required this.documentID);
```

Pass documentID from the parent screen of UpdateScreen.